# Yasnippet stops compile error highlighting

Tags: yasnippet, compilation

I have been compiling my C++ project using `M-x compile` which I like because it provides highlighted links to my errors:

[image: highlighted compile errors]

However after adding:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path
         "~/.emacs.d/plugins/yasnippet")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
```

to my .emacs file this no longer works:

[image: compile errors not highlighted]

I'd really like to use yasnippet and have my compile errors highlighted, anyone have any idea how to fix this? I'm using GNU Emacs 24.3.1

Comment: If this reproduces in `emacs -Q`, then it's likely a bug, and you may want to consider [reporting it](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the issue [here](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/issues/672), this was fixed by updating yasnippet to the version from github. The version on the GNU ELPA repo (0.8.0) is quite old.